# Layouts for multiple screen sizes

Tags: android-layout, intellij-idea

Android documentation says:

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

How can I test this on IntelliJ IDEA without creating several AVDs? They give the option to simulate the screen size (inches), but how do I know which is considered large, xlarge or the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer here (check table 3): http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing